# How to create prototype instances of "targetObject" using "MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean" in Spring-Quartz?

Tags: java, spring, prototype, javabeans, quartz-scheduler

I've been playing around with Spring-Quartz for a while now, and there is one thing I'm unable to achieve - I want to use the "MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean" in order to execute a method in an class I have, and I want new instance of that object created each time the trigger is triggered.

The part of my application context that is related to Quartz looks like this:

```
  <bean id="myTask" class="com.test.TestImpl" scope="prototype" /> <!-- The bean that does the actual work -->  
<bean id="testMethodJobDetailBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="myTask"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="run"/>
    <property name="concurrent" value="false"/>
</bean>
 <bean id="testTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="testMethodJobDetailBean"/>
    <property name="startDelay" value="25000"/>
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000"/>
 </bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="testTrigger"/>
            </list>

        </property>
</bean>
```

My objects' names are different in the original file, and I have 2 more jobs (with a trigger for each of them) but they are not relevant for my question.

The above configuration works, and my task is executed every 5 seconds. The problem is, it always uses the same "com.test.TestImpl" instance which is problematic for me since the object have state that affects its behavior.

I've read that Quartz's default behavior is to create a new instance of jobs each time, but when using Spring-Quartz, Spring manages the life-cycle. This indeed seems logical, and that's why I added the scope="prototype" to the "myTask" bean, but it didn't help.
I also tried to set the scope of the JobDetailsFactory bean to prototype, and it didn't help.

I think that the problem is that the JobDetail object created by "MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean" is not defined as prototype, and since is it wrapping my bean, and being created only once - my bean won't be created more than once.

I would like to know if someone else encountered this as I wasn't able to find any useful information regarding this issue, and wasn't able to find anyone that experienced the same behavior.
And of course, if you know how to fix this, I would be happy to hear about it.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I am having the same problem.